# Python/Flasks/Socketio, socketio.emit(...) doesn't emit

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

i'm having trouble to use flasks socketio, it seems that when I call `socketio.emit('my event', 'my message')` it doesn't emit any event at all...

So this is my setup:

```
|
+--/static     <-- css/js/etc.
|
+--/templates  <- only home.html
|
+--flask_app.py
```

`home.html` is just a simple chat window with these scritps and it works without any problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('request', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('message', function(message){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(message));
        console.log('Message received');
    });
</script>
```

I have a function that tracks changes in my models data, and emits a event
to notify everyone that data has changed, the problem is that when I call
`socketio.emit(...)` nobody gets the notification.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import event

app = Flask(__name__)

# App configuration
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somekey!'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

socketio = SocketIO(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Simple model
class Person(db.Model):


    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name
        }

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

# Whenever a user emits 'request' event via javascripts socketio
@socketio.on('request')
def handle_request(message):
    emit('message', str(message), broadcast=True)

# Whenever values are changed in Persons table
@event.listens_for(Person, 'after_update')
def receive_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    print(str(target.serialize))
    socketio.emit('message', str(target.serialize)) # <------ This doesn't emit any event...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?
Thanks

### Edit

Forgot to mention that I do changes in database via console and it prints out `print(str(target.serialize))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Found the solution

First I must install redis with

```
pip install redis
```

Then I should change this line:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

to this:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://')
```

Now from another console I can change values in my database and everyone will see the changes